# Search all files containing text

Tags: linux, find, grep, file-search, busybox

With Busybox, how do you search for an expression within a bunch of files recursively through a bunch of directories, but only look through text files?

We don't know what the file's suffix is going to be; it could be .sh, it could be nothing, it could be something else.  I was considering somehow basing the search on encoding although I am not quite sure what the encoding would be either.

I've tried `busybox grep -r` but it searches through binary files too, which wastes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` supports the option `--binary-files` to treat binary files as `binary`, `text` or `without-match`. The last option should skip binary files. It is equivalent to `grep -I`. I did a test and it seems Busybox's `grep` supports `-I` to skip binary files.

`grep` is not "magical" in determining if a file is binary or text: it simply checks the first few bytes to see if they seem to be text or not and assumes the same for the rest of the file (according to `man grep`).

---

Sidenotes: one could emulate this by e.g. comparing if `head -1 myfile` of a file equals `head -1 myfile | strings`. If `file` is available it is even more reliant, but it is not in Busybox, and most likely not on the system if Busybox is primarily used.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between a binary file with the struct

```
struct MyBin
{
    byte a;
    byte b;
    byte c;
}
```

with the values

```
myBin.a = 70;
myBin.b = 111;
myBin.c = 111;
```

And a text file with the text `Foo`?

All a text file is, is a binary file that you interpret using special look up codes called Character Encodings (ASCII, UTF-8, ect...). So there is no easy way to tell "Binary Files" apart from "Text Files".

There may be a way to exclude files that have the execute bit set, or only search files under a file-size (I doubt your text file is over 1 MB) but I do not have enough knowledge on how to filter the grep results to give a example of how to do it.